# Apk stuck "in prod" in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to release an update for an app on Google Play. I've already changed the version name/number on Manifest and have uploaded a second version in the apk section within Google Play. However, it's be more than a day, and the status is still "in prod." Is there something I forgot to do?!

Answer (score 6):

FYI, "In prod" means its already updated and available on play store to download.

Comment: I'm facing same from. Browser is showing latest version but in phone play store is showing old version of app. How to solve this problem?

Comment: "In Prod" does not necessarily mean it is live. The Last published date tells which apk is live on playstore. I don't know, My app is doing this. It's not going live since 4 days. It says it is in Prod but still Last published apk date is couple of weeks old which is previous version.

Comment: @Viks did you get this issue resolved? I am also facing same issue for update

Comment: @AniruddhAmbarkar Check your app's version code which is in prod state. Make conform that your correct version is in prod state. You will get update after hours.

Comment: have checked in whats shows in play store console is updated version code & version name and in Play store page is older version

Answer (score 2):

Now you have 3 stages for releasing an app:
alpha
beta
and Production.

Production is the stage where you release the app to the public. The other 2 are just released for the Google+ groups/communities that you want.

If you search for your app in you google play app you can see the version number.