# How to cancel Android publish process?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add an application for beta testing for first time. I made a mistake and instead of adding it on beta tab I did it on production one.

I'm trying to cancel the publish process but I'm not able to do so.

I've switched to advanced mode and clicked "deactivate" but I get the following error

> This configuration cannot be published for the following reason(s):
>
> You must have at least one active APK.

I don't want to publish the App. This other question [Unable to deactivate APK accidentally uploaded to Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006165/unable-to-deactivate-apk-accidentally-uploaded-to-prod) seems to indicate that there is no possibility to revert this mistake. How is that posible?????

**EDIT**

It seems I'll be able to unpublish this app. Is it possible to publish it again later using the same package id and just change the version?

Comment: I never got a mail telling me my apps are on the market

Comment: @eduyayo: that's a relief....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to deactivate APK accidentally uploaded to Prod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006165/unable-to-deactivate-apk-accidentally-uploaded-to-prod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can unpublish but once your application has been live on the market you cannot delete it.Only older version can be deleted

Comment: But once it is on the market I can take it out from there, right?

Comment: you can unpublish that

Comment: Will be able to publish it later just changing the version or I'll have to change the app identitty to republish?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cancel the publishing, at least I think that if you upload a beta apk with higher version name it replaces the active app.
The error I think it's because the app is not published yet it takes around 2 hours to publish.

Comment: It seems I'll be able to unpublish it. Will be able to publish later an unpublished app without changing the app package?

Comment: I think so, google play it's a little bit tricky with this kind of things.