# Can not disable production app in Google Play Developer Console in favor of beta

Tags: android, apk, beta

I uploaded my beta version of the app and I want to deactivate the production version.  I figured out how to click switch to advanced and deactivate the production app but it will not let me save it, always give me in red at the top " The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors." but I see no errors show on the form.

Any suggestions on how to get past this?

Here is a screen shot: [image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to deactivate APK accidentally uploaded to Prod](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006165/unable-to-deactivate-apk-accidentally-uploaded-to-prod)

Answer (score 12):

This has happened to me quite recently. I tried to unpublish an app and got same error. I found that the questionnaire for content rating was incomplete. I updated that, applied the suggested content rating, and voila...I could unpublish the app without any error. Try to see if anything in your app settings need update, fix them and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I had to provide a url for a privacy policy in this section. Didn't have to be a real url to a privacy policy. Just had to put something there so unpublish would work. Pretty terrible experience.

Answer (score 2):

More then likely you have not visited the developer console in a while. Lots of new things have changed with android in the last couple of years. You will need to fill out the new required information.

This includes things like rating, and new images that are required.

If you just want a tool to generate assets and than unpublish the application checkout [norio.be](http://www.norio.be/android-feature-graphic-generator/) it's a graphics generator.

Answer (score 2):

**The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors.**

Its happen when you can't complete the store listing

Answer (score 1):

go to store presence >content rating > fill the form > apply> then you can finally  unpublish it with out any errors