# The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors

Tags: android, expansion

I get error:

> The application could not be saved. Please check the form for errors

when upload new apk with new expansion file.
When i try use old expansion file it's ok. And I try upload old expansion with new name, it's still error.

Comment: similar issue look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35208117/5241603

Comment: And here : http://stackoverflow.com/q/31370618/5241603