# Cancelling an APK update in Google Developer Console

Tags: google-play, updates, cancellation, google-developers-console

I accidentally pushed the "Update Production" (can't remember exact wording) button in Google Developer Console, but I didn't actually change the form. But now it just says "Processing Update...".

How can I cancel this process? Do I have to wait the "up to 24 hours" to submit the actual update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only option left is unpublish immediately once update is complete. so that older version will be active again.

Cannot do anything else.

Reference - [Unable to deactivate APK accidentally uploaded to Prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006165/unable-to-deactivate-apk-accidentally-uploaded-to-prod)

But I agree, there has to be better way!